# Replacing one css3 animation with another

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I want to be able to set an animation effect for a certain image on my site (slow transition of the background position). But after a certain user interaction, I want to be able to remove that animation and switch to a different one. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to it:

```
.element{
    animation: first 1s forwards;
}
.element.clicked{
    animation: second 1s forwards;
}
```

This way, you will not have to remove a class. With jQuery, just use this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){$(this).addClass('clicked');});
```

Comment: There's no need for !important - the second selector has more specificity than the first.

Comment: @dc5 It's true that any browser supporting CSS3 animation will support the correct order. I removed `!important` from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You add and remove a class with the animation properties

```
.classOne {
    animation: one 5s forwards;
}
.classTwo {
    animation: two 3s forwards;
}
```

and the javascript to do so

```
var obj = document.getElementById('animatedElement');
obj.onclick = function() {
    obj.classList.remove('classOne');
    obj.classList.add('classTwo');
}
```

the equivalent jQuery

```
$('#animatedElement').on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('classOne').addClass('classTwo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `:not` selector and toggling an element class you can do something like this to change current element animation:

```
#xpto:not(.anim) {
    -webkit-transition:background-position 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:background-position 1s ease;
    -o-transition:background-position 1s ease;
}

#xpto.anim {
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#xpto:not(.anim):hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#xpto.anim:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdBrB/)**